# Differential equations separable

Tags: calculus

I have tried to solve this but i have come to dead ends:
$$tdy+ydt=ty^2dt$$
This is my go:
$$tdy+ydt=ty^2dt$$
$$tdy+(y-ty^2)dt=0$$
But I don't know how to remove the t effectively

Comment: $tdy+ydt=d(ty)$ and write $\dfrac{d(ty)}{(ty)^2}=\dfrac{d(t)}{t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$y=0$ is a solution.
let us look for another solution.

divide by $y^2$ and put $$z=1/y . $$

it becomes
$$-tz'=t-z$$
$$z'/z=1/t \implies z_h=\lambda t $$
the variation of the constante gives
$$\lambda '(t)=-1/t $$
$$\implies z_p=-t\ln (|t|). $$
$$z=z_h+z_p=\lambda t -t\ln (|t|) $$
and finally
$$y=\frac {1}{\lambda t -t\ln (|t|)} $$

Comment: But how did you integrate that?

Answer (score 0):

$$t\,dy+y\,dt=d(ty)$$ and $$ty^2\,dt=(ty)^2\,\frac{dt}t$$

Then

$$\frac{d(ty)}{(ty)^2}=\frac{dt}t$$
which integrates as

$$-\frac1{ty}=\log|t|+C.$$

Finally,

$$y=-\frac{1}{t(\log|t|+C)}.$$

Comment: We found exactly same solution. magic.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: but I forgot $y=0$ :-( :-)